# How can i simulate REST post request with json data in browser

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest, symfony

I have the web application where the frontend is in `ExtJS` and backend is in `PHP`.

The forms are build in Extjs and its making PUT and POST request to server for saving data.

The josn data is posted like this

```
{"id":"101","description":"user1","active":true}
```

Now for debugging i would like to directly call this `URL` in `browser` so that i can use `var_dump` for helpful messages.

As the request is AJAX by Extjs , so its very difficult to see messages through firebug.

Is there any way to make this request from browser and see response in rendred html.

I don't want to make form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome you can use the [Postman Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm). It allows you to send pretty much any type of data and see the results.

Comment: i installed extension , but where i can paste the json data

Comment: Once you enter the URL for the service (where you want to POST or PUT the JSON, select the RAW button beneath (there is also form-data, x-ww-form-urlencoded, and binary), then in the drop down list next to it chose, JSON.  Click Send when you are ready to submit.

Comment: i get this error while using that tool `&quot;txt&quot;` format not supported

Answer (score 5):

For firefox you can use [restclient](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/) plugin. Its also very easy to use, and userfriendly.

Also, if you know [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), you can do it programatically from PHP.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on good terms with `curl` you can just use it directly with `-d (--data)` option like that:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json localhost:8080/path/to.json
```

Where `data.json` is a JSON file.

Anyway, representation of an extension might be more intuitive and readable.

Comment: You need to add option ```-H``` before the ```Content-Type``` argument to make it work.

Comment: inline JSON can be write as -d {\"data"\:\"test\"}

Answer (score 2):

If the requests being made through a `store` in extjs, you can use `Ext.getStore` to find the store and create global variable.  Then you could manipulate this global variable in the console.

i.e. write following in console

`var s = Ext.getStore('myStore')`

then after firing you can now manipulate this global in console

`s.proxy.extraParams.myChangedValue = 'newValue'`

`s.load()`

The response from the server will be in the network panel in chrome browser or use firebug extension for firefox.  You can also add a `callback` or `listener` to the `load` event to `console.log()` what was parsed by the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is the Chrome's [Advanced REST Client App](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo%3Fhl%3Den-US&ei=GksAVebIGIPCggT_qYGQDw&usg=AFQjCNEkroM42vfwzL0_5_3WgPLuFCnAZg&sig2=PBPOBOkAUvqW6jp-dHDQkw&bvm=bv.87611401,d.eXY).  It isn't as powerful as the postman extension but I think it is a little bit easier to use.